# Access result of previous promise inside a second

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using the `return pattern` to prevent me from making promise ugly cascade.
Here is an exemple, I'm calling two function one after the other `myfunction1` and `myfunction2`

```
myfunction1().then((value1) => {
  return myfunction2()
}).then((value2) => {
  console.log(value1)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

How can I access `value1` inside the `then` of the seconde function ?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass it through your chain. That's why I started using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
try {
    var value1 = await myfunction1();
    var value2 = await myFunction2();
    console.log(value1)
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to "chain" your promises like this:

```js
myfunction1().then((value1) => {
  return myfunction2().then((value2) => {
    console.log(value1)
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err)
}
```